# How to make conditional result appear in a barchart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to extract the data from the excel and display those result with more than 200 to appear in a barchart.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df2 = pd.read_csv("monthly.csv",index_col='month')
df3 = df2[df2.monthly > 200]

data = np.genfromtxt("monthly.csv", skip_header=1, dtype=[('month','U10'), ('amount','f8')], delimiter=",",
missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])
#plt.bar(df['month'], df['amount'], width = 0.5)
labels = list(set(data['month']))
plt.bar(x=data['month'], height=data['amount'])
plt.xlabel('month', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(labels, fontsize=40,rotation='vertical')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

However, the output is wrong and the label did not appear. Can someone advise where did I do wrongly?
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk1qy.png)

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdUze.png)

Comment: Are you able to provide your data source `monthly.csv`?

Comment: It looks as though your x data is not being formatted correctly, can you confirm the `dtype`? Also you are not plotting your filtered data frame `df3`, could this be the issue?

Comment: @PaddyHarrison, what do you mean by x data?

Comment: @unleashed I have experienced similar plot formatting issues when plotting a time vs value graph and the x-data (time in this case) is being interpreted as a string rather than a number or `datetime`. This would be the first thing I would check. If you are able to provide your CSV (or even a small subset of it) then I would think you would get an answer more quickly!

Comment: @PaddyHarrison, I have included an image of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

@unleashed I used your code with the dataset you provided and got the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt("monthly.csv", skip_header=1, dtype=[('month','U10'), ('amount','f8')], delimiter=",",
missing_values=['na','-'],filling_values=[0])
labels = list(set(data['month']))
plt.bar(x=data['month'], height=data['amount'])
plt.xlabel('month', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(labels, fontsize=40,rotation='vertical')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: OP code]

As you can see this code works well, but the plot formatting issues you are having is because matplotlib is interpreting your x-data `data['month']` as strings, ie. discrete data, and the x-axis scaling is based on the number of bars you have in the chart (10 in this example). If we change the x-axis limit to `(0, 15)`, this scaling is demonstrated, and also the strange x-axis label formatting problem in the question also becomes present - the labels start to overlap:

```py
plt.xlim(0, 15)
```

[image: xlim example]

**Proposed solution**

I would recommend using pandas to parse the data, and cast the `month` column directly as `datetime`, matplotlib will know how to handle it:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import  axes
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data = pd.read_csv("monthly.csv", na_values=['na','-'], delimiter=",", parse_dates=['month'], dtype={'amount':np.float64})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(data['month'], data['amount'], width=timedelta(days=25))
ax.set_xlabel('month', fontsize=14)
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=90)
ax.grid(True)
```

[image: pandas]

Note that now the x-axis units can be represented by `datetime`, for example the bar widths are 25 days.

Also we can set the x-axis limits using datetime objects and the plot will scale properly, for example below, the x-axis label spacing changes so there is no overlapping issue:

```py
ax.set_xlim(datetime(1992, 1, 1))
```

[image: pandas xlim]